# How can I check whether the NEST simulator module is MPI aware?

Tags: nest-simulator

It's easy to overlook the output during the build and install process, so I'd like to know if there is a way in NEST's python module to check for successful MPI integration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no dedicated Python function for it (yet), but you can get it from the SLI `statusdict`:

```python
>>> print(nest.ll_api.sli_func('statusdict/have_mpi ::'))
True
```